# How to sort String in Arraylist

Tags: sorting, arraylist, collections

I have an ArrayList where I add customers. What i wnat to do is that i want to sort them, so they appear sorted on Console.

```
private static ArrayList <Kund> klista = new ArrayList<>();
Kund kundd = new Kund("a","b");
System.out.print("Namn: ");
String namn = scr.next();
System.out.print("Adress: ");  
String adress = scr.next(); 
if (!namnKontroll(namn)){
    System.out.println (namn + " " +"har lagts till \n");
    klista.add(kundd);
    Kund k = new Kund(namn, adress); 
    klista.add(k); 
}else{
    System.out.println("Kunden med det namnet finns redan i systemet!");
}
```

// this is how i add customers to my ArrayList. So now, how it is possible to sort those names in ArrayList. I want to sort them with Collections. thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+sort+list ?

Answer (score 1):

Try use [Collections.sort(klista, theComparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)). You will need create a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), like this:

```java
public class KundComparator implements Comparator<Kund> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Kund o1, Kund o2) {
        // write comparison logic here
        return o1.getID().compareTo(o2.getID());
    }

}
```

Then use the Comparator:

```java
Collections.sort(klista, new KundComparator());
```

If you are using Java 8, you can do like this:

```java
Collections.sort(klista, (Kund k1, Kund k2) -> k1.getId().compareTo(k2.getId()));
```